# How do I copy my Selenium project from one laptop to another?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have developed a hybrid framework using a maven project, POM, TestNG, etc. It's running fine now I wanted to copy the entire project from one laptop to another laptop so on first laptop I can continue with my work and second laptop I can use it just to execute the scripts which will same my lot of time.
On daily basis I take backup on OneDrive. I have some questions:

1. Can anybody guide me how to copy the entire project? Do I need to have the same version of Java and Eclipse on second laptop? Anything else need to be installed?
2. On a daily basis how do I get the backup data from 'OneDrive' to a second laptop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you want a repository. Use Github, Gitlab, Bitbucket, just.. git in general. That's exactly what this is for.

As for your Java and Eclipse versions, you need to look at your running version of selenium, what packages you are using, etc, and determine for yourself what Java version you should be running. The latest version of the jdk is going to have everything the earlier ones had, so it's usually a safe bet to use the latest stable version. Your Eclipse version should always be the latest as well as it is just an IDE and shouldn't have any impact on how your program runs.

Another option is to use a virtual environment (a *virtual-env*) and upload that to your git repository, this is a localized version of java present inside the project, that can be carried along with it, although this bloats your repository massively.

Comment: Laif  & abhimanyusapra thanks  as  of you have suggested for Github,  but i am new to all this so need to study how can i implement it. I am working in a company where no developers and as a automation tester i am the only person. Testing their readymade software before it giving it to the client. Still should go with Github or any other options are available?

Comment: @dh.purvi Definitely go with github, it will make your life much easier. There are lots of great tutorials available (such as [this one](https://product.hubspot.com/blog/git-and-github-tutorial-for-beginners))  and it isn't as hard as it may seem at first.

Comment: i do have  jdk_1.8.0_221 in my first laptop do i need to install the same one in another laptop, right?

Comment: @dh.purvi yes, either that version or a newer one.

Comment: You mean both should have same version?

Comment: No, they don't both need to have the exact same version. Just install the latest jdk and you will be fine @dh.purvi

Comment: If i update the java version in my existing laptop from jdk_1.8.0_221 to jdk_1.8.0_241 will affect to my existing project?

Comment: @dh.purvi It might, but all you'd have to do to fix it is point Eclipse at the new version, you also don't technically have to do that though. Just set up eclipse and jdk normally on the new computer. As long as the new version is the same or newer it won't matter. There's no reason for you to change the version on the first machine.

Comment: In new laptop only jre1.8._241  and Eclipse are installed but not able to start Eclipse, it showing the error  'java was started but returned exit code =13.  C:\Program Files (x86)COmmon FIles\Oracle\Java\Javapath\javaw.exe. etc. THis error because i think JDK is missing.

Comment: @dh.purvi yes, you have to have the jdk. Install one.

Comment: https://github.com/pricing  -- Can i go for 'Team' option? is it enough for my requirement?

Comment: @dh.purvi I'm unsure what you're referring to.

Comment: I thought so because only 2 users(between my 2 laptops) will be using, Anyway thanks.

Comment: No, one user, yourself. @dh.purvi

Answer (score 0):

Try using git and github and you don't have to take backup and need to work on a specific laptop